# Convert Plus Plugin Close Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, modal-dialog

I am using the convert plus plugin as a modal popup. However, I need to disable the popup from closing once the form has been submitted. If anyone has some insight on the issue, I would uber appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Is the form being submit using AJAX?

Comment: I think so, not 100%. Looks like it.

Comment: If it is then you should be able to do this using the settings in the modal, or by not manually closing it when the form is submit. We can't tell you how to do that exactly without seeing your code. If you're not using AJAX, then it's not possible without some mechanism to re-open the modal when the page next loads, which is ugly and far from ideal